# Least common multiple : number of triples $(x,y,z)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x, y, z$ be positive integers. Find the number of triples $(x,y,z)$ satisfying

$[x,y] = 72, [x,z] = 600, [y,z] = 900$.

$[a,b]$ = lcm of $a,b$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track,

$[x,y] = 2^3\cdot3^2$ so $v_2(x) = 3$ or $\;v_2(y) = 3$

$[x,z] = 2^3\cdot3\cdot5^2$ so $v_3(x) = 1$ or $v_3(y) = 1$

$[y,z] = 2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5^2$ so $v_3(y) = 2$ or $v_3(z) = 2$

Since $[x,z] = 2^3\cdot3\cdot5^2$, so $v_3(z) \leq 1$ and $v_3(y) = 2$

Please suggest me on how to proceed.

Comment: Because of $[y, z] = 900 = 2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$, we cannot have $v_2(y) = 3$, so we must have $v_2(x) = 3$ (which means that $x = 8$ or $24$). Also, $v_5(z) = 2$, clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if I'm on the right track,
>
> $[x,y] = 2^3\cdot3^2$ so $v_2(x) = 3$ or $\;v_2(y) = 3$

This is not correct. We have $\max(v_2(x),v_2(y))=3$.

---

Since
$$[x,y]=72=2^3\cdot 3^2,\quad [x,z]=600=2^3\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^2,\quad [y,z]=900=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$$
we can write
$$x=2^{v_2(x)}3^{v_3(x)},\quad y=2^{v_2(y)}3^{v_3(y)},\quad z=2^{v_2(z)}3^{v_3(z)}5^\color{red}{2}$$
satisfying
$$\max(v_2(x),v_2(y))=3,\quad \max(v_2(y),v_2(z))=2,\quad \max(v_2(x),v_2(z))=3$$
$$\max(v_3(x),v_3(y))=2,\quad \max(v_3(y),v_3(z))=2,\quad\max(v_3(x),v_3(z))=1$$
from which we have
$$v_2(x)=3,\quad v_3(y)=2$$
So, a necessary and sufficient condition is
$$\max(v_2(y),v_2(z))=2\quad\text{and}\quad \max(v_3(x),v_3(z))=1,$$
i.e.
$$(v_2(y),v_2(z))=(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(0,2),(1,2)$$
and
$$(v_3(x),v_3(z))=(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)$$
Therefore, the answer is
$$5\times 3=\color{red}{15}$$

Comment: Nice and simple solution. Thank you both.